# MySQL check for uniqueness of a set of attributes?

Tags: mysql, validation, unique

What I'm trying to do is, I need to perform a uniqueness validation. However, I am not simply checking *"if the name iggy already exists in DB?"*. I need to check for uniqueness of a set of attributes.

Here's what I mean by checking for uniqueness of a set of attributes. Let's say that I need to check for the uniqueness of the columns/ attributes: `type`, `partNum`, and `name`. I need to check if a set of `type`, `partNum`, and `name` of a row is unique.

1. If I find two rows with the same `type` and `name` but they have different `partNum`, they are considered unique.
2. If I find two rows with the same `type` but they have different `name` and `partNum`, they are considered unique.
3. If I find two rows with the same `type`, `name`, and `partNum`, they are NOT unique.

```
id type  partNum  name
-----------------------
1  A     partA    nameA  # assume this exists
2  A     partA    nameB  # unique
3  A     partB    nameA  # unique
4  B     partA    nameA  # unique
5  A     partA    nameA  # NOT unique b/c type, partNum, and name match with 1
```

What is a good strategy / MySQL code to compare attribute sets from the `type`, `partNum`, and `name` columns?

Comment: You can do [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html). Or you can just `GROUP BY` on those 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
         type, partNum, name
 FROM mytable;
```

[GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) approach:

```
SELECT type, partNum, name
 FROM mytable
GROUP BY type, partNum, name;
```

`GROUP BY` with [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) approach, if you want to see the list of `id` have the same uniqueness:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids, type, partNum, name
 FROM mytable
GROUP BY type, partNum, name;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=669134670165a31457cd509761ccea78)